# Is there a way to automatically remove a Cabal package with its depedencies?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I would like to know if there is some tool,script or any other way to uninstall packages and their dependencies that were installed using the Cabal tool?

Comment: To remove a single cabal package, you can `ghc-pkg hide <package>`. I don't know about dependencies. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I experiment with many packages and every time I install a package many others come in and then I choose not to use the package and the dependencies stay in. For example I tried happstack but happastack installed blaze-html and many other packages that I don't know which of them belong to happstack and which not. So I decided to uninstall happstack but I am not sure that I have deleted all the package dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in way of doing this and I've never heard of a tool or script that can do it.

The best approach is to use a *sandbox*. For example in a fresh directory:

```
cabal sandbox init
cabal install <whatever>
...
```

Then just blow away the directory when you're done with it.

You can also explicitly specify the sandbox directory with `--sandbox=...` - otherwise it goes in `.cabal-sandbox` inside the current directory.